# Programmatically panning the map doesn't move polygon labels

Tags: angular, typescript, bing-maps

I'm using the [Angular Maps (X-Map)](https://github.com/infusion-code/angular-maps) library with Bing Maps to generate a map with labeled polygons on it. Elsewhere in my app, I have items that can be clicked to pan to specific locations on the map. The problem is that when this happens, the labels on the polygons don't move with everything else - but if you then use the mouse to manually pan the map, they suddenly jump back into place.

Here's a simple example that demonstrates the problem ([Stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cqcbgs)*):

*Note: if you get "Argument 1 of Node.appendChild does not implement interface Node" while testing this, manually refreshing the preview makes it work again. Not sure if that's related or not, but it doesn't happen in my actual code.

**HTML**

```html
<x-map style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" [Zoom]="8" [Latitude]="lat" [Longitude]="0">
  <x-map-polygon [Paths]="paths" [ShowTooltip]="false" [ShowLabel]="true" [Title]="title"></x-map-polygon>
</x-map>
<button (click)="clicked()">Click Me!</button>
```

**Component**

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  paths = [{latitude: 0.1, longitude: 0.1}, {latitude: -0.1, longitude: 0.1}, {latitude: -0.1, longitude: -0.1}, {latitude: 0.1, longitude: -0.1}]
  title = "test"
  lat = 0
  clicked () {
    this.lat += 0.1
  }
}
```

When you click the button, it moves everything on the map down except for the "test" label:

[image: An animation demonstrating the label not moving properly]

Digging around in the library's source code, it's ultimately making a call to `setView` from the [Bing API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-api/map-class), and I can't find any options to force a refresh of the labels or manually move them. What can I do here?

Answer (score 0):

When `title` property is specified for polygon component, [label is getting created](https://github.com/infusion-code/angular-maps/blob/4a3186ec407235e5fe1cc4990a4e9f102a54af0c/src/models/bing/bing-polygon.ts#L411) along with a polygon instance. The way how `BingMapLabel` is implemented, its position could be explicitly updated by triggering Map `viewchange` event:

```
clicked () {
    this.lat += 0.1;

    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addOne(this.nativeMap, 'viewchangeend', () => {
      Microsoft.Maps.Events.invoke(this.nativeMap, "viewchange", null); //trigger viewchange event to update label position
    });
}
```

where native Bing Map instance could be retrieved via `MapPromise` event:

```
<x-map (MapPromise)="mapReady($event)" ... >
    ...
</x-map>

mapReady(mapPromise){
  mapPromise.then(map => {
      this.nativeMap = map; //save map instance 
  });
}
```

[Updated StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3rudvs)